# Segmentation fault when using map

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when doing anything with my map. Its declared like this:

```
typedef std::map<uint16_t, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, uint16_t> > > bitMap_t;
```

And then I have a private class member using this map

```
        private:
        bitMap_t m_bitMap;
```

My code using this map looks like this

```
uint16_t i = 1;
uint16_t j = 0;
uint16_t reg = 0;
uint16_t regIndex = 0;
uint8_t regSizeWords = 0;

for (regIndex = 0; regIndex < NUMBER_OF_BIT_REGS; regIndex++) {
    for (i = 1, reg = m_regList[regIndex].address; reg < (m_regList[regIndex].address + REGS_SIZE); reg++, i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m_regList[regIndex].signalsAndBitMasks.size(); j++) {
            ostringstream signalName;
            signalName << m_regList[regIndex].signalsAndBitMasks[j].first << "." << i;

            m_bitMap[reg].push_back(make_pair(signalName.str(), m_regList[regIndex].signalsAndBitMasks[j].second));
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tested just doing a m_bitMap.clear() before all this code and that didn't work either. So I guess it has something to do with nested map, vector and pair or?
The segfault error looks like this:

> `std::less<unsigned short>::operator() at stl_function.h:230 0x805e8da
>
>   std::_Rb_tree<unsigned short, std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > >, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > > >::_M_lower_bound() at stl_tree.h:986 0x8063a0f`
>
> `std::_Rb_tree<unsigned short, std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > >, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > > >::lower_bound() at stl_tree.h:745 0x8063531`
>
> `std::map<unsigned short, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > >, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > > >::lower_bound() at stl_map.h:701 0x806311a`
>
> `std::map<unsigned short, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > >, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned short const, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, unsigned short> > > > > >::operator[]() at stl_map.h:447 0x8062bc1`
>
> `srvmgr::MbBitMap::InitBitMap() at mbbitmap.cpp:175 0x80620cc`

Comment: What line in *your* code is the error originating from?

Comment: Other advice:  a complex line like `m_bitMap[reg].push_back(make_pair(signalName.str(), m_regList[regIndex].signalsAndBitMasks[j].second));` might be better broken into several lines (make the pair first, call any nontrivial functions) so you can trace the error out more specifically.

Comment: I have done that and the problem arises when I write m_bitMap[reg]. I also tried writing m_bitMap.clear() and the problem was still there

Comment: if `m_bitMap[reg]` crashes then it means either your standard library is very broken and noone else has ever noticed (very unlikely) or you've corrupted the map somehow (this is likely), possibly by scribbling on memory. Try a memory error detector like `valgrind`

Comment: also, are you sure that the *this* is correct when you execute that code that uses the map?  it is likely that the *this* is incorrect (i.e. calling a function from a null/invalid pointer to the class).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the nesting. If you crash on `clear` it's very likely that your map is corrupt. How are you creating and using the object *containing* the map? Have you made sure that you're following the "rule of three", if applicable?

Answer (score 1):

By far the most common reason is not actually having a map in the first place.

You write that the map is `private: bitMap_t m_bitMap;`, i.e. a member of an object. I'll bet that you have a pointer to this object (`MbBitMap` ?), but for some reason unrelated to `std::map` this pointer is invalid.